# Using Redux SubApps with React Router

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

Is it possible to use this approach [isolating SubApps](https://redux.js.org/recipes/isolating-subapps) with React Router?

The issue is each time the Route change, the SubApp will re-render and then the redux store get disconnected.

```
class BigApp extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router history={history} >
        <Route component={SubApp1} />
        <Route component={SubApp2} />
        <Route component={SubApp3} />
      </Router>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. I had the same problem. The way i solved it is [here](https://github.com/me-12/single-spa-portal-example). The crux of the solution is to maintain a global store at root application and  local stores for each sub applications and use Observer pattern between them.